# android app signature changes when moving to another pc for development

Tags: android

I made an app for android but needed to move to another pc due to hardware failure. Now, the question pops up from android studio that an app with the same package name is on the tablet, but a different signature, and ask to uninstall. Uninstall fails however because the app is device owner to implement kiosk mode ( pinned mode in android terms ).

So, I'm stuck. Why is the signature different while the project is exactly the same ?

Comment: Did not work. I decided to factory reset the tablet to make it work again. Can you tell me, will this happen for non debug apk tha same or will that install acording to package name only ?

Answer (score 0):

Copy your keystore form your pc to other pc .
KeySotre path  `C:\Users\{username}\.android\debug.keystore`

Comment: unfortunatly, did not work. We have a common server where the user is preserver over several systems, so it should have been the same. I decided to factory reset the tablet and redo changing the device owner.

Comment: You find *.keystore compile project copy to other pc and compile . Before restrat android studio or eclipse .

Comment: I decided to factory reset the tablet to make it work again. Can you tell me, will this happen for non debug apk the same or will that install acording to package name only ?

Comment: Yes , Each Developer a keystore  needs for published application .

Answer (score 0):

When you run your project in android studio it generates default hash for debug mode, and APK installed on your device is generated with a different hash so it prompts you.